# How to change Wordpress dashboard login url to website URL?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress website

> www.example.com

Once a user goes to URL he sees Wordpress login page and below URL in the browser address bar.

> www.example.com/wp-admin/....

I want to change that so when people go www.example.com they see the login page and the url in the browser address bar remains same www.example.com or in other words I dont want that slug and redirect text seen in the address bar. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can rewrite `wp-admin`, but you could create your own login code to display on the Home page. To start with, [wp_login_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/)() displays a login form:

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```

You could add this code to a page template, or create a shortcode so it can be added via the Dashboard editor like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'stackoverflow_login_shortcode' );
function stackoverflow_login_shortcode() {

    add_shortcode( 'stackoverflow-login-form', 'stackoverflow_login_form_shortcode' );

}
function stackoverflow_login_form_shortcode() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return '<p>You are already logged in!</p>';
    }
    return wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false ) );

}
```

Now you can add `[stackoverflow-login-form]` into a page.